# Add binding for validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I want to create Spring endpoint for validating Java Object. I tried to implement this example:

https://www.baeldung.com/validation-angularjs-spring-mvc

I tried this:

```
public class WpfPaymentsDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 15)
    private String card_holder;

    private String card_number;
    ....
}
```

End point:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
      public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> handleWpfMessage(@PathVariable("unique_transaction_id") String unique_transaction_id,
          @RequestBody WpfPaymentsDTO transaction, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> errors = result.getAllErrors().stream()
              .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.OK);
        } 

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO("test"));
      }
```

When use submits Angular form I would like to validate all fields. But currently I get this error: `Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>`

What is the proper wya to implement this?

Comment: Method returns `ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO>` but when `hasErrors` is true, you return `ResponseEntity<List<String>>`. In the example you posted, `ResponseEntity<Object>` is returned. You can make changes accordingly, either change method's return type, or set errors info in `StringResponseDTO` object and return it.

Comment: Can you paste working example please?

Comment: Show what are your expectations of responses (with/without errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [`@Valid`](https://spring.io/blog/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/) annotation in your method signature.
If you look at the example you are quoting, you will see that it's used on the `User` object.

So in your case:

```
@Valid @RequestBody WpfPaymentsDTO transaction
```

Also you are returning two different class types in [`ResponseEntity<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

1) `ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO>` in a validation successful scenario

2) `ResponseEntity<List<String>>` in a validation failure scenario

The above is the reason for:

> But currently I get this error: Cannot infer type arguments for
>   ResponseEntity<>

If you look at the example you are quoting, the method return type is `ResponseEntity<Object>`.

So your method should change to:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id}", 
     consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, 
     produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleWpfMessage(
                 @PathVariable("unique_transaction_id") String unique_transaction_id,
                 @Valid @RequestBody WpfPaymentsDTO transaction, 
                 BindingResult result, 
                 HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
```

#### Update:

> Is there a way to find out for which variable the validation error is
>   raised?

Yes, you can get all field binding errors like this:

```
List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
for (FieldError error : errors ) {
    System.out.println ("Validation error in field: " + error.getField() 
                    + "! Validation error message: " + error.getDefaultMessage() 
                    + "! Rejected value:" + error.getRejectedValue());
}
```

Comment: I have a question: I get error but I can't find for which variable I get this error. Is there a way to find out for which variable the validation error is raised?

Comment: Yes I found it but for error.getObjectName() I get `wpfPaymentsDTO`. How I can get `card_holder` in above case?

Comment: getField() will return you the attached field

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445649/return-list-of-errors

Answer (score 2):

try using Angular Reactive Forms (FormGroup and FormControl). 
I think it's easier that way.

Comment: I agree but also for security I need to implement this code. Can you give me a hand please?