# Return list of errors

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I wan to return a list of errors using this Response object:

```
public class StringResponseDTO {

    private String response;

    public StringResponseDTO(String response) {
        super();
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

I use this code to generate errors:

```
List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors ) {
          System.out.println ("Validation error in field: " + error.getObjectName() 
                          + "! Validation error message: " + error.getDefaultMessage() 
                          + "! Rejected value:" + error.getRejectedValue());
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO(error.getField() + " " + error.getDefaultMessage()));
        }
```

I want to return a list like this:

```
response: {
   errors: [
      field_name: message,
      second_name: second_message
           ]
}
```

Do you know how I can modify the code? Probably I need add constructor?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` in place of `println()`.

Comment: If you return inside the loop, the loop ends. If you want to return a list of errors, then the objectyou return should contain a list, and you should populate that list with all the errors before returning.

Comment: You should use a serializer like Jackson or ObjectMapper or Gson to convert the List<FeildError> to json string.

Comment: Can you show me working example, please?

Comment: The example is not a valid JSON. Is errors an array or an object? You use square brackets like it's an array, but you have field_name: val1, second_name: val2 there as if it was an object with 2 fields - field_name and second_name. What should it be actually, array or an object? What JSON do you want in an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response: {
   errors: [
      field_name: message,
      second_name: second_message
           ]
}
```

You need to use the following classes to model the above json:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonTypeName("response")
class StringResponseDTO {

    private List<String> errors;

    public StringResponseDTO(final List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(final List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

You can construct the response as:

```
List<String> errorsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
for (FieldError error : errors ) {
     System.out.println ("Validation error in field: " + error.getObjectName() 
                     + "! Validation error message: " + error.getDefaultMessage() 
                     + "! Rejected value:" + error.getRejectedValue());
          errorsList.add(error.getField() + " " + error.getDefaultMessage());
}

return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new StringResponseDTO(errorsList));
```